# Вращать объект по мышке | Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

Здравствуйте!

Мне нужно что бы объект вращался "по мышке" (т.е. что бы он был повернут к мышке).

Rotate toward position mousex и mousey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Алгоритм  вот какой

1. определяем угол поворота (угол между осью абсцисс и направляющим
   вектором)
2. поворачиваем объект вокруг своего центра
3. перемещаемся к цели (к мышке)

а для поворта изображения необходимо повернуть весь холст, предварительно переместив начало координат в точку, вокруг которой необходим поворот, нарисовать изображение и обратно переместить начало координат в исходную точку.

https://jsfiddle.net/d4w9LnLu/

```js
(function() {
  const cnv = document.getElementById("cnv");
  const ctx = cnv.getContext("2d");
  
  let mouse = new Vec2();
  let distanceVec = new Vec2();
  let myImg = new ImgSceneObject(
     new Image(),   
     'http://www.java-forums.org/attachments/java-2d/1449d1319003532t-tank-game-help-please-tankeast.jpg', 
     50, 50,
     new Vec2(200, 200)
  );
  let angle = 0;
  let translationVec = new Vec2(myImg.pos.x, myImg.pos.y);
  let direction = new Vec2(); 
  let translationSpeed = 2;
  
  function initApp() {
    cnv.width = window.innerWidth;
    cnv.height = window.innerHeight;
    document.onmousemove = mousemove;
  }  
  
  function Vec2(x=0, y=0) {
    this.x = x; this.y = y; 
    
    this.add = function(v) {
      this.x += v.x;
      this.y += v.y;
      return this;
    }; 
    
    this.sub = function(v) {
      this.x -= v.x;
      this.y -= v.y;
      return this;
    }; 
    
    this.multScalar = function(s) {
      this.x *= s; this.y *= s;
      return this;
    }; 
    
    this.dot = function(v) {
      return this.x*v.x + this.y*v.y;
    }; 
    
    this.rotate = function(angle) {
      this.x = this.x*Math.cos(angle) - y*Math.sin(angle);
      this.y = this.x*Math.sin(angle) + y*Math.cos(angle);
      return this;
    }; 
    
    this.translate = function(v) {
      this.add(v);
      return this;
    };
    
    this.length = function() {
      return Math.sqrt(this.x*this.x + this.y*this.y);
    };
    
    this.normalize = function() {
      const invLength = 1.0/this.length();
      this.x *= invLength;
      this.y *= invLength;
      return this;
    };
  }    
  
  function ImgSceneObject(img, src, w, h, imageCenter) {
    loaded = false;
    img.onload = function() { loaded = true; }
    img.src = src;
    this.pos = imageCenter;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;    
    this.update = function(angle, v) {  
      ctx.save();           
      ctx.translate(this.pos.x, this.pos.y); 
      ctx.rotate(angle);     
      this.pos.x = v.x;
      this.pos.y = v.y;      
      if (loaded) {      
       ctx.drawImage(img, -this.w/2,  -this.h/2, this.w, this.h);
      }
      ctx.restore();
    };
  }
  
  function updateScene() {
    renderTarget();
    myImg.update(angle, translationVec);
    distanceVec.x = mouse.x - myImg.pos.x;
    distanceVec.y = mouse.y - myImg.pos.y;
    if (distanceVec.length() > 10) {
     translationVec.add(direction);  
    }
  } 
  
  function renderTarget() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(mouse.x - 7, mouse.y - 7, 7, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
  }
  
  function gameloop() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cnv.width, cnv.height);
    updateScene();
    id = requestAnimationFrame(gameloop);
  } 
  
  function mousemove(e) {  
   mouse.x = e.clientX;
    mouse.y = e.clientY;    
    direction.x = mouse.x;
    direction.y = mouse.y;  
    angle = Math.atan2(mouse.y-myImg.pos.y, mouse.x-myImg.pos.x);
    direction.sub(myImg.pos).normalize().multScalar(translationSpeed);
  };
  
  initApp();
  gameloop();
}());
```

```css
#cnv { border: 1px solid #000; }
```

```html
<canvas id="cnv"></canvas>
```

буду вопросы по реализации - задавайте

Comment: То что нужно! Огромное спасибо :))

Comment: @TitaN пожалуйста

Comment: `this.angle = Math.atan2(Mouse.y-this.centralImagePoint.y, Mouse.x-this.centralImagePoint.x);` - почему не работает?

Answer (score 3):

```js
var canv = new Canv(canvas.getContext('2d'),
                    canvas.width, canvas.height);
var ax = rand(canvas.width);
var ay = rand(canvas.height);
var bx = rand(canvas.width);
var by = rand(canvas.height);
var speed = 3;

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  bx = e.clientX - rect.left;
  by = e.clientY - rect.top;
}, false);

var timer = setInterval(function() {
  var angle = Math.atan2(by - ay, bx - ax);
  if (angle < 0) angle += 2 * Math.PI;
  
  ax += speed * Math.cos(angle);
  ay += speed * Math.sin(angle);
  canv.clear();
  canv.drawCircle(ax, ay, '#0e0');
  canv.drawLine(ax, ay, angle, 'black')
  canv.drawCircle(bx, by, '#e00');
}, 50);

function rand(max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
}

function Canv(ctx, w, h) {
    this.radius = 5;
    this.clear = function() {
        ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
        ctx.rect(0, 0, w, h);
        ctx.fill();
    };
    this.drawCircle = function(x, y, color) {
        ctx.strokeStyle = "#000";
        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x, y, this.radius, Math.PI * 2, false);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
    };
    this.drawLine = function(x, y, deg, color) {
        ctx.strokeStyle = color;
        ctx.lineWidth = 1;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(x, y);
        ctx.lineTo(x + Math.cos(deg) * 2 * this.radius,
                   y + Math.sin(deg) * 2 * this.radius);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
    };
}
```

```css
input[type="range"] {
    width: 50%;
}
input[type="text"] {
    width: 75px;
}

#panel {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div id="panel">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Мне нужно вращать картинку, так что `ctx.lineTo(x + Math.cos(deg) * 2 * this.radius, y + Math.sin(deg) * 2 * this.radius);` не подходит